# how to pass parameters with spaces to autoIT run command from selenium

Tags: java, string, selenium-webdriver, autoit

```
String cmc = "D:\\fileFolder\\File Name-" + CurrentDate() + ".xlsx";

String autoitexec = "D:\\AutoITScripts\\AttachFile.exe" + cmc;

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(autoitexec);
```

Above code is my current code. I am passing autoIt script location and file location from string autoitexec. I am unable to run above code ..

Comment: Above code is my current code.Iam passing autoIt script  location and file location from string autoitexec.Iam unable to run above code ..

Comment: Which pat of the above code is Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

```
String cmc = "D:\\fileFolder\\File Name-" + CurrentDate() + ".xlsx";

String autoitexec = "\"D:\\AutoITScripts\\AttachFile.exe\" \"" + cmc + "\"";

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(autoitexec);
```

Escape double quotes with a backslash. i.e. 2 double quotes inside a double quoted string is `" \" \" "`.

Spaces are required between the command and each of the arguments.